# Loaded object in three.js - wrong position

Tags: javascript, three.js, virtual-reality

I'm making a virtual tour editor and I need to put some map pins on certain coords. I've used just spheres as "placeholrders" while developing the backend logic. Now when everything works, i want to replace the spheres with actual pin objects. The problem is, that when I load the pin object and set same coords like for those spheres, the pin is on different position.

I've tried to put those coords to root object, mesh object, always the same result. Also tried to log coords into console and it's correct.

```
     ADD_HOTSPOT_TO_SCENE: function(context, hotspot) {

        // SPHERE CODE
        let geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 1, 60, 40 );
        let mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00} );
        let cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );

        // set position of hotspot
        cube.position.set(hotspot.x, hotspot.y, hotspot.z);

        // set unique object name to pair with hotspot object
        cube.name = hotspot.getUniqueID();

        cube.scale.x = hotspot.scale / 10;
        cube.scale.y = hotspot.scale / 10;
        cube.scale.z = hotspot.scale / 10;

        // add object to scene as draggable object
        context.commit('ADD_DRAGGABLE_OBJECT_TO_SCENE', cube);

        // OBJECT CODE
        let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(Tour.mapPinTexture)
        });

        context.state.loader.load(Tour.mapPinObj, function(object){
            object.position.set(hotspot.x, hotspot.y, hotspot.z);
            object.name = hotspot.getUniqueID();
            object.traverse( function ( node ) {
                if ( node.isMesh ) {
                    node.material = material;
                }

            } );
            var box = new THREE.BoxHelper( object, 0xffff00 );
            context.commit('ADD_DRAGGABLE_OBJECT_TO_SCENE', object);
            context.commit('ADD_TO_SCENE', box);
        });
    }
```

I need to put the object on same position like the sphere. Current output looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KSFN.jpg .. Do I miss something?

Comment: What loader are you using in order to load the pin object? Can you also share the file in this thread? In any event, try to ensure that the origin of the pin's geometry is centered (similar to a sphere geometry). You can do this in a content creation tool like blender or with `three.js` (one approach is demonstrated here: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/model-not-casting-receiving-shadows/6146/9?u=mugen87)

Comment: I'm using OBJLoader (https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/OBJLoader). I'm using Vuex for core actions and the file is pretty heavy. The main functionallity is in function I posted above. Then the object is just added into scene and rendered. I paired this editor with Unity app and the same object works fine with given coords.

Comment: I found the issue. Calling center() on object's geometry solved it. Thanks for your help.